# How to ignore user's shell when running script by user

Tags: shell, gnu-parallel

I have to run script by user. That user's shell has changed to `/script/script1` in `/etc/passwd` file. When I run the script, it is getting SHELL as a /script/script1.

Comment: Why not just remove it from the command line?

Comment: _Doctor, Doctor, it hurts when I hit myself on the head like this...?_  So, it works without GNU Parallel.  That's good.  Why do you need to use GNU Parallel?  Why not avoid using it, thereby avoiding the problem?  Have you looked at the man pages for GNU Parallel to see how you avoid (re)using the user's login shell when running commands?

Comment: There's no mention of SHELL on the manual pages.  You may need to show us the actual invocation of `sem`.  Also, why would you want two parallel backups of Oracle running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, now that I see the script and the passwd entry, I think I understand what is going on.  sem is trying to execute your command line using your shell.  If you printenv before the sem do you see that SHELL=home/bkup:/script/script1?

If so, then just export SHELL=/bin/bash (or /bin/sh, whatever) on the line before running sem

If this doesn't work, please show us the output of printenv.

Comment: @user1497667: Did you actually try what I suggested?  Checking and/or changing the defintion of $SHELL?

Comment: @Dhammika: Not specifically, but assuming the script works correctly when run by a user in Solaris then add `printenv > /tmp/$USER.env` in the script, change the affected user's to /bin/ksh, log in as the user, run the script, then save the output, change the user's shell to the script, and re-run.  diff the two printenv output and report back